# Как присвоить стили атрибутам тэгов vuetify

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify

Ребята , помогите присвоить стили к :headers.

```
<v-data-table
        :headers="dataSecretsTableHeaders"
        :items="dataSecrets"
        :items-per-page="5"
        class="table"
      >
```

Как я этого могу добиться?

Comment: проинспектировать код, не?

Comment: Стили применяются не к атрибутам тега, а к тегу. Поэтому для начала правильно сформулируйте вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

```
v-data-table["headers"] {
  ...style for tag v-data-table with attribute "headers"...
}
v-data-table["headers"="dataSecretsTableHeaders"] {
  ...style for tag v-data-table with attribute "headers" equal to "dataSecretsTableHeaders"...
}
```